# php - format time with strftime

Tags: php, datetime, date-format, strtotime, strftime

I use strftime to format time from a mysql datetime col over a multilanguage website.
My goal ist to get this, like a "decimal time":

```
6 p.m. to 7.30 p.m. or
2.15 p.m. to 5 a.m.
```

and not sg. like that:

```
06:00pm to 07:30pm
02:15pm to 05:00am
```

Maybe someone can help me out!

I tried with this (My experimental sourcecode):

```
// $var comes in datetime format from mysql
function formatDateTime($format,$var) {
return strftime("$format",strtotime($var));
// Formats: http://php.net/manual/de/function.strftime.php
}

// mysql fetch: ...
echo formatDateTime('%I:%M%P',$row['dateTimeStart']) ... to ...
echo formatDateTime('%I:%M%P',$row['dateTimeEnd'])
```

Comment: you may need either [PHP Date Format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) or [MySQL Date Format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Comment: If format depends on the time (which in your example it does), you'll have to examine the given time and switch formatting around based on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this should do what you want:

```
function formatDateTime($date = 'now', $format = '%l:%M %P') {
    $ret = strftime($format, strtotime($date));
    return str_replace(array('am', 'pm', ':00'), array('a.m','p.m', ''), $ret);
}
```

Example usage:

```
echo formatDateTime('1385914593');
echo formatDateTime('08:00:04 AM');
echo formatDateTime('13:26:04');
```

Output:

```
5:30 a.m 
8 a.m 
1:26 p.m
```

Comment: i tried your code, it solves half of the problem ;) i get now  8:00a.m to 3:30p.m but i would like to have "the empty minutes" gone away: eg. 8 a.m to 3:30 p.m

Comment: yes i know this is very well but i woul like instead of 2:00 a.m > 2 a.m (5:30 is great!)

Comment: you can just change the return to `return str_replace(array('am', 'pm', ':00'), array('a.m','p.m', ''), $ret);`

Comment: Glad to have been of help. Cheers! :)

Comment: @user2987790: Please don't edit answers into the question. The edit you just made to the question is effectively the same as this answer, so I've rolled back the edit. If you really want to post a different solution, feel free to post it as an answer. :)